# Defining limit of integral using fractions

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, python

I was trying to derive limit form of integral and I got the below. But I'm not sure what is wrong about it. I learned about it in class today and I'm having all the rectangles under a function summed since the width can be defined by $b/r$ and the height can be $f(bx/r)$

$$\int_{0}^{b} f(x) \,dx = \lim_{r \to \infty} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{r-1} \frac{b}{r}f\left(\frac{bk}{r}\right)\right)$$

Here I am setting $r$ to the number of rectangles (it approaches infinity), $f$ is the function and inside the summation it slowly sums each value until $b$ is reached.

I even tried running it using Python and it seems to work correctly for the basic functions I've tried

````
def calculate_limit(f, r):
    total = 0
    for x in range(r + 1):
        total += a/r * f(x*a / r)
    return total

def f(x):
    return x**2
    
r = 1000
a = 2

limit = calculate_limit(f, r)
print(limit)
```
````

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Sorry, I am editing it right now.

Comment: It should be $\sum_{x=0}^{r-1}$ or $\sum_{x=1}^r,$ or else you are summing $r+1$ rectangles. (The limit is still correct, since $(r+1)/r\to1,$ but the sum as written is not an area of $r$ recrangles.)

Comment: $a$ shouldn't be a global - it is a parameter of calculate_limit. Also, that name is wrong, it doesn't calculate the limit, it calculates an estimate.

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: This limit will work if the function $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Right I forgot integrals can exist if there's a finite number of jump discontinuities

Comment: Also yes, the python code is an approximation. Sorry if thats not clear. I don't know how to code a limit solver in Python but will try to learn it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(This is a community wiki answer! Please feel free to improve it to your liking.)*

Nice self discovery!

Indeed there is no particularly wrong part of your discovery. The equality holds if $f$ is continuous (or even Riemann integrable) on the interval $[0, b]$:

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{b} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} f\left(\frac{kb}{n}\right)\frac{b}{n} \tag{1}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f\left(\frac{kb}{n}\right)\frac{b}{n} \tag{2}
\end{align*}

*Remarks:*

- In $\text{(1)}$, the right endpoint of the subinterval is used to calculate the height of each rectangle, whereas in $\text{(2)}$, the left endpoint is used.
- Although the above equality is enough to establish a theoretical definition of a (rudimentary version of) definite integral, you may have already noticed that the approximation still deviates from the actual value even when the number $n$ of divisions is large. This opens up the question that eventually leads us to the area of numerical integration, where a much more efficient ways of approximating integrals has been studied.

---

I also brushed up your code for fun:

```
from typing import Callable


def calculate_limit(f: Callable[[float], float], n: int = 10, b: float = 1.0) -> float:
    sum: float = 0
    dx = b / n
    for k in range(n):
        sum += f(k * dx) * dx
    return sum


for n in [10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000]:
    limit = calculate_limit(lambda x: x**2, n, b=2)
    print(
        f"Simluated value using {n} divisions\n    = {limit}\n"
    )  # Exact value is 8/3 = 2.666...
```

Comment: Thanks! this is very helpful and I really want to study more on this. Im just a AP calc student and like to learn by trying to figure out generalizations.

Comment: We are just learning about trapezoids and midpoint integrations which now make sense to me better.